# How to force logout linked account in actions-on-google?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

In the [docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in), the sign in functionality looks like this:

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask(new SignIn('To get your account details'))
})
```

However, I can't find how to force logout a user who just signed in. Anyone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why you want to be able to do this?

Comment: Hi @Prisoner, thanks for the comment. My use case is I want to login using another account.

Comment: Which Sign-In/Account Linking method are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google SignIn

Comment: If you are the one who is developing this action, then it might be possible that you will not see the name of the Action at https://myaccount.google.com/permissions . Instead, you will see 11 characters of your account linking client id. Once you find your action Click-> Remove Access.

Answer (score 1):

"Logging out" of an account linked with Google Sign In is tricky, particularly if you're using voice matching as well, since the account sent to the Action is the same account as the one you setup the Assistant device with.

You can go to https://myaccount.google.com/permissions and remove permission from the app/Action/project. Once you do this, the Action will no longer get your user information. (This isn't Action specific - it is a core component of Google Sign In across all platforms.)

The other alternative you have is to reset your Assistant device and set it up with a new account. Then when you go to the Action with this reset device, the account won't be linked.

Answer (score 1):

A explicit sign-out function does not seem to be available. However, this can be a good design decision as the user should be logged in to a particular service "as long as possibly allowed". Therefore, when releasing your apps to production, consider looking at the validity of the access_token and refresh_token on your authorisation server to control the "login period".